# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable selectivesearch

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-recognition

```
File "<ipython-input-23-e640c8ab269c>", line 1, in <module>
img_lbl, regions= selectivesearch.selectivesearch(img, scale=500, sigma=0.9, min_size=10)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Why am I getting this error? I'm confused.

What do you need to know to answer my question?
I trying to run this code

```
import skimage.data
import selectivesearch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = skimage.data.astronaut()
img_lbl, regions= selectivesearch.selectivesearch(img, scale=500, sigma=0.9, min_size=10)
regions[:10]
[{'labels': [0.0], 'rect': (0, 0, 15, 24), 'size': 260},
{'labels': [1.0], 'rect': (13, 0, 1, 12), 'size': 23}]
```

whan i use function `selective_search` get this error 
`AttributeError: module 'selectivesearch' has no attribute 'selective_search'`

Comment: Simple typo; it should be `regions= selectivesearch.selective_search(...`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you imported `selectivesearch` inside you selective search module, and then called it instead of calling a function.

The error says you can't call a module like a function

Comment: when I use<selective_search> function get this error< AttributeError: module 'selectivesearch' has no attribute 'selective_search' >